# Provider hosted app Access denied for Tenant FullControll permissions

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, csom

We are working on a provider hosted app for SharePoint. Our app performs app only accesses and needs Tenant Full Control permissions which we define in the AppManifest.

Since yesterday we get the following error:
`Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.` when we recompile the app and deploy it to our dev site.

The app is not trusted via Site Content => Manage permissions like it worked early.

We found a Wokraround, but it's quite tedious and doesn't allow easy debugging.

Workaround is to manually trusten the app via `https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`

1. Build and deploy the app as usual.
2. Copy the new ClientId from web. config
3. go to appinv. aspx and trust the app, use permissions xml from AppManifest. xml

[image]

If you now remove the SharePointApp project as a start project from the solution, you can work without any problems and the ClientId will not be regenerated with a rebuild.

Has anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: Has anyone been able to observe the behavior yet? Microsoft has closed my ticket, but the problem still exists!